# Trying to populate fields based on contact lookup

Tags: apex, visualforce, trigger, dynamic-visualforce

Action support is refreshing overall page.Only following section should be refreshed.Not happening may be m missing small point.

Vf page:

```
<apex:pageblockSection title="Prepared For" columns="2"  id="con" >   
 <apex:inputField value="{!quote1.Contactid}">
 <apex:actionsupport event="onchange" action="{!fetchdetails1}" rerender="Con"/>
 </apex:inputField>  
 <apex:inputField value="{!quote1.Phone}"/>                 
 <apex:inputField value="{!quote1.Email}"/>
 <apex:inputField value="{!quote1.Fax}"/>    
</apex:pageblockSection>
```

Class:

```
public void fetchdetails1(){
if(quote1.contactId !=null ){con=[SELECT AccountId,CurrencyIsoCode,email,Fax,Id,MailingAddress,MailingCity,MailingCountry,MailingLatitude,MailingLongitude,MailingPostalCode,MailingState,MailingStreet,MasterRecordId,MobilePhone,MOM__c,Name,OwnerId,Phone,Salutation,Title FROM Contact where id=:quote1.contactId limit 1];
  quote1.Phone=con.Phone;
  quote1.Email=con.Email;
  quote1.Fax=con.Fax;
 }}
```

Answer (score 0):

rerender is case sensitive....and you are missing a space

in addition, to trigger the on change the input element has to loose focus

try

```
<apex:actionsupport event="onchange" action="{!fetchdetails1}" rerender="con"/>
```

Comment: I have space but still it is not working. I have edited as above.

Comment: Did you change Con to con?